# What package do I need to import for the Jackson mongodb DBquery functions to compile in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, mongo-jackson-mapper

I have this query string :

```
coll.find(and(DBQuery.greaterThanEquals("createdOn", startDate), DBQuery.lessThanEquals("createdOn", endDate),DBQuery.is("user_email",userEmail)));
```

I am getting the error :

```
cannot find symbol [symbol: variable DBQuery] [location: class models.food.UserMeal]
```

Now a plain DB query

coll.find(); is working smoothly. What package am I missing for this to work?

Update :

I tried importing :
import org.mongojack.DBQuery;
but instead got the error :
package org.mongojack does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to [official documentation](http://mongojack.org/queries.html) you should import exactly `org.mongojack.DBQuery`.

So your problem is with library dependencies. Obviously you have missed `mongojack` library, e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongojack</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongojack</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I resolved the dependency according to the official documentation but now I am getting "cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : method find(org.mongojack.DBQuery.Query)"

Comment: @jackOfAll this is another question. We have helped you solve the problem which was mentioned in the post

Answer (score 2):

Mongojack is the dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongojack</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongojack</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I resolved the dependency according to the official documentation but now I am getting "cannot find symbol [error] symbol : method find(org.mongojack.DBQuery.Query)"